# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric exception

Tags: sql-server

I tried to execute the query shown below in SQL Server Management Studio, but I get this error

> Converting data type nvarchar to numeric exception

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUM(CAST([dbo].[Orders].[CustomerID] AS DECIMAL (38, 4)))) = 1 
            THEN CAST(SUM(CAST ([dbo].[Orders].[CustomerID] AS DECIMAL (38, 4))) AS INT) 
            ELSE NULL 
    END AS [Column1] 
FROM
    [dbo].[Orders]
```

Can anyone help me to clear this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop and Think. In general, summing an ID column makes no sense. Such a sum has no meaning unless there is something implicit in your schema. You could have 1000 orders for Customer 1 or 2 orders for Customer 500. Both situations sum to the same value - is that useful?

In addition, your error means that your ID column is not numeric. In this case, your use of isnumeric should be **INSIDE** the sum expression. The sum aggregate will ALWAYS return a numeric value; there is no useful reason to place it inside of an isnumeric/coalesce function.

And lastly, your schema is concerning. Someone chose to define the ID column as nvarchar - why? Perhaps there was a good reason but it seems unlikely at this point. That choice indicates that the table designer **intended** to allow any character in the ID column - which you now have confirmed. So I refer back to the first paragraph - at best you can only sum a subset of values from the column. Is that useful information?

Ultimately, if you need to do this then you reverse the relative positions of sum/isnumeric in your query.

```
select sum(case when isnumeric(CustomerID) = 1 
    then cast(CustomerID as ...) else 0 end) as Column1
from dbo.Orders;
```

And keep in mind that isnumeric is not as useful as one might expect. You can search the forums for alternatives. If you are a current version of sql server, you can use try_cast without the complexity of case/isnumeric.

Perhaps you meant to COUNT the orders for each customer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC( 
        SUM (
            CAST ([dbo].[Orders].[CustomerID] AS DECIMAL (38,4))) 
        ) = 1 
    THEN CAST( 
        SUM (
            CAST ([dbo].[Orders].[CustomerID] AS DECIMAL (38,4))) 
        ) AS INT
    ELSE NULL END AS [Column1] 
FROM [dbo].[Orders]
```

It's a bit difficult to fix bad code when you do not format it correctly and provide no sample data.